# Search bar becoming active when pressing edge of navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I have a navigation bar which has a button on the left and search bar. The search bar was set as a title view. The issue that i am running into is that if I press the edge of the navigation bar the search bar becomes active. Is there a way to avoid this?

Code:

```
//setup search controller
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchController?.searchBar

//set up button
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton
```